# Datatables footer callback coming back NaN for all row total

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to using datatables and for some reason when I implement the footercallback code referenced here: https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html
my page 'total over all pages for the amount column keeps coming back as NaN. The total per page works fine.

**Html:**

```
<div class="col-lg-9 table-responsive" id="tableCont">
<div class="dataTables_paginate"></div>
<table style="width:2850px;" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-responsive" id="fundQueryDataTbl"
       data-body="@Url.Action("GetFundingData", "FundingProfiles", new { fundingYear = Model.FiscalYear })"
       data-header="@Url.Action("GetColumnNames", "FundingProfiles", new { fundingYear = Model.FiscalYear })">
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#fundQueryDataTbl').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        //Column names identified as DDL search - 5/6/16
        var txtSearchNames = ['Funding Category', 'Funding Subcategory', 'Award Class', 'Grant Class Desc', 'Grant Type Desc', 'Us Territory'];

        this.api().columns().every(function () {

            var column = this;
            var columnName = $(this.header()).text();

            //Certain columns were decided upon to have text searches as opposed to DDL. 
            if (txtSearchNames.indexOf(columnName) > -1) {

                //Client wanted title to have / in it - cannot set that in FQ Model prop name.
                if (columnName === "Us Territory") {
                    $(this.header()).text('US/Territory');
                    this.draw();
                }

                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.header())).on('change', function () {

                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

                        column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                });


            } else {

                $('<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">')
                    .appendTo($(column.header())).on('keyup change', function () {

                        column.search(this.value).draw();
                    });
            }


        });
    },

    //responsive: true,        
    ordering: false,
    bPaginate: true,
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: '80vh',
    scrollX: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    dom: 'Brtip',
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'pageLength' },
        $.extend(true, {}, cleanHeaderRow, {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Save in Excel'
        }),
        $.extend(true, {}, cleanHeaderRow, {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Save in CSV'
        })
    ],
    ajax: {
        "url": url,
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "footerCallback": function (tfoot, data, start, end, display) {

        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                i : 0;
        };

        //// Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column(16)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);


        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column(16, { page: 'current' })
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.table().footer()).html(
            '$ ' + pageTotal + '  ' + total
        );

        $(tfoot).find('th').eq(0).html('$' + pageTotal + ' over all total: $' + total);
    },
    columns: declareColumns(columnKeys)
});
```

**Datatable image:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your table html ?

Comment: yes @Leopard I will update now

Comment: Is the amount column you are totalling ?

Comment: @Leopard yes that's the one I'm trying to add up

Comment: @cxwilson  Just a guess since I haven't used it but have you tried turning off "deferRender"?  Since that causes the pages to be rendered on demand and your "page total" works but your "table total" does not.  We should be able to figure out how to get this to work even with defer render on but wanted to see if it works with "deferRender" turned off.

Comment: @cxwilson also if you can add an example in JS Fiddle that shows the issue that would help a lot.  It gives us a concrete example to play with

Comment: hi @Aliester, I turned off defer render and it still does the same thing. I would like to add it to a jsfiddle but I have this thing tied up in so many databases so it'll take me awhile.

Comment: @cxwilson can you please make a fiddle with same data ?

Comment: @Leopard I figured out the issue. In one of the row we are displaying a negative amount and it is display as ($171,408). The code isn't sure how to calculate it with parentheses. Do you have an suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: @Leopard I am trying to do something like this:
if (b.toString().includes("(")) {
                        b.replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
                        return intVal(a) - intVal(b);
                    } else{
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }

but this is not working, it says Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Comment: @Leopard Updated with new screenshot of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was fighting the comment system so just going to put this here.  With your updated comment that your parenthesis are causing the issue for negative numbers here is what I would suggest:

```js
  // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
var intVal = function (i) {
  if(typeof i === 'string') {
    let multiplier = /[\(\)]/g.test(i) ? -1 : 1;
    
    return (i.replace(/[\$,\(\)]/g, '') * multiplier)
  }
  
  return typeof i === 'number' ?
    i : 0;
};


console.log(intVal("$123,234"))
console.log(intVal("($123,234)"))
console.log(intVal(new Date()))
console.log(intVal(55))
```

I would highly suggest you look into some custom render functions instead of what you have.  You can define a different render function per column if you like and return data formatted in different ways depending on the render request (display, order, filter, ..etc.)